# signing eclipse plugin to be always valid

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to sign my plugin jars using keytool for generating the key.

I know there is -validity option but how to set it to make the plugin always valid and never expires.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the keytool documentation:

> **Validity Period** : Each certificate is valid only for a limited amount
>   of time. This period is described by a start date and time and an end
>   date and time, and can be as short as a few seconds or almost as long
>   as a century. The validity period chosen depends on a number of
>   factors, such as the strength of the private key used to sign the
>   certificate or the amount one is willing to pay for a certificate.
>   This is the expected period that entities can rely on the public
>   value, if the associated private key has not been compromised.

From this it is clear that you can't have a certificate that never expires.